# Get the column of a user selected cell using vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

Refer to this question: [Let the user click on the cells as their input for an Excel InputBox using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353711/let-the-user-click-on-the-cells-as-their-input-for-an-excel-inputbox-using-vba).
I use this line of code `Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the cell you want to edit.", Title:="CELL TO EDIT", Type:=8)` to ask the user to select a cell. If the cell that is selected is in column G then I will need to call a subroutine. So, I need to figure out what column the selected cell is in.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use `If rng.Column = 7 Then` where 7 corresponds to G. Btw, don't forget to add error hadler for case when user press CANCEL and nothing selected

Comment: That's just `rng.column`. (Column G = 7.) Is that your question? Oh, simoco. :)

Comment: It worked great. I have the error handler already but thanks for the tip. I used `If rng Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub`. Put it as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rng.Column` property to return column number:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the cell you want to edit.", title:="CELL TO EDIT", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'column G=7
    If rng.Column = 7 Then
       'do something
    End If
End Sub
```

If user can select more than one cell, change

```
If rng.Column = 7 Then
```

to

```
If Not Application.Intersect(rng, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
```